# Gravityform easy calculation - but total is not beginning from 0

Tags: wordpress, calculation, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have a pretty simple calculation in gravityform, but because I add +1 and +0.5 to what people are filling out in the input fields, then the total from the begining is showing a number instead of only 0.

Example:

Field A +1
Field B +0.5

Calculation Field A x B x 295. But because I add +1 and +0.5 to what people put in the input field, then the total from the beginning, shows 147,5. Because it calculate 1*.0.5*295 = 147,5.

But I want the total just to show 0 until people are filling out the input field.
How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet for a code-based solution will probably be to use the [gform_calculation_result](https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_calculation_result/) filter and check a value of `1` or `0.5` and return 0 instead.

```js
gform.addFilter( 'gform_calculation_result', function( result, formulaField, formId, calcObj ) {
    if ( result == 1 || result == 0.5 ) {
        result = 0;
    }
 
    return result;
} );
```

An alternate approach would be to use conditional statements right in the calculation formula, powered by our [Gravity Forms Advanced Calculations](https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-advanced-calculations/#conditional-statements) plugin.

You could check if the field has a value and provide a formula for that and return `0` otherwise.

```
if ( F1 > 0 ):
    F1 + 1
else:
    0
endif;
```